# split paragraph by the first sentence

Tags: jquery, regex, text-segmentation

I have this div, and i want to add some style to the first sentence.

```
<div class="text">dfgdfg.asdhasd</div>
```

I am trying this code but is not working as expected.

```
var text = $('.text').html().split(".")[0]+".";

$(".text:contains("+text+")").css("color", "red");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kuLNP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only going to work if there is only one .text element on the page.

```
var elem = $('.text');
var textParts = elem.html().split(".");
var first = "<span class='red'>" + textParts.shift() + ".</span>";
elem.html(first + textParts.join("."));
```

If there are multiple it will need an each loop.

```
var elems = $('.text');
elems.each( function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var textParts = elem.html().split(".");
    var first = "<span class='red'>" + textParts.shift() + ".</span>";
    elem.html(first + textParts.join("."));
});
```

Of course this uses a class to set the color, basic class would be

```
.text .red{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/a68dS/1/

Comment: textParts.shift is not a function ?

Comment: There was a typo in the code, I fixed it. You probably grabbed it right before I edited it.

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that all sentences are terminated with periods, which is not the general case.  Also, it would erroneously believe that "<a class="foo.bar">baz</a>" contains two sentences '<a class="foo' and 'bar">baz</a>' See a more general solution below.

Comment: Also note that, as of 7:34PM EST, the referenced fiddle does not work as it highlights the entire example text.

Comment: @epascarello, there is possible to pass two arguments in split? to catch . or ?

Comment: @loops regexp `split(/\.\?/g)` but you will have issues joining it back together. Look at the other solution.

Comment: split(".") is very dangerous for any more complex scenario. It should be based on element child nodes.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak And how do you get element child nodes with plain text?

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wp5kw/

Assuming a paragraph of:

```
<p id="para"> This is a test. Is it? Yes, it is indeed! 
You might ask, is this a sentence? To which I would reply 
with a resounding "YES"!!!</p>
```

To grab all the sentences, use:

```
var sentences=$('#para').text() // get example text
        .match(/[^\.\!\?]+[\.\!\?]+/g) // extract all sentences
        .map(function(s){ // (optional) remove leading and trailing whitespace
            return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
        });
```

To highlight the first sentence, use:

```
var count=0;
$('#para2').html(
    $('#para')
        .text()
        .match(/[^\.\!\?]+[\.\!\?]+/g)
        .map(function(s){
            s=s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
            return count++
                ? s
                : '<span style="color:red">'+s+'</span>'
        }).join(' ')
);
```

The regular expression assumes that periods, exclamation and question marks are used to terminate a sentence, and is:

```
[^\.\!\?]+         -- one or more non-sentence terminals
[\.\!\?]+          -- followed by one or more sentence terminals
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in an element, you can't apply css to text nodes:

```
var $div = $('.text');
var text = $div.text();

$div.html( text.replace(/.+?\./, '<span>$&</span>') );
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ezojic/1/edit